# Objective-C JSON-RPC Request issue

Tags: objective-c, json, json-rpc

I have a problem with my JSON-RPC query.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{id:1,method:getHolidays,jsonrpc:2.0}";
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString,nil];

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [jsonString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://neilo.webuntis.com/WebUntis/jsonrpc.do?school=htl_v%C3%B6cklabruck"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"Content-type: application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"\n\n\noutput: %@",returnString);
```

As Result I get this output:

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7a1efafd; line: 1, column: 3]"}}

The Result should be:
->`message = not-authenticated`<-

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: `NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"id":@1,@"method":@"getHolidays",@"jsonrpc":@"2.0"}; NSData *jsonData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];`... `[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];` If you copy/paste the string JSON into a JSON Validator, you'll see it's not valid (missing quote surrounding strings). It should be `{"id": 1,"method": "getHolidays","jsonrpc": 2.0}`, which `NSJSONSerialization` would take care of it and simplifies since it's constructed from dictionary (easier to change parameter).

Comment: Yea Got it!  

NSString *jsonString = @"{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getHolidays\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}";

Comment: I'd recommend to use `NSJSONSerialization` rather than constructing your JSON String yourself. It's safer (there is an error parameter, if it's not valid, it's easier to modify, especially with mutable NSMutableArray/Dictionary, if there are key that can be added or not). Also, avoid `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, prefers async ones (with `NSURLSession`).

Answer (score 0):

> was expecting double-quote to start field name:

Your server is telling you that your JSON is invalid.

If you test `{id:1,method:getHolidays,jsonrpc:2.0}` on a JSON validator (http://jsonlint.com/ for instance), it would tell you so. As said, it's missing surrounding quotes for each strings (keys/values): `{"id": 1,"method": "getHolidays","jsonrpc": 2.0}` is valid.

So, as you tried `@"{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getHolidays\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0‌​\"}"` works.

I'd recommend to use `NSJSONSerialization`, sample not tested (may not compile):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"id":@1,
                           @"method":@"getHolidays",
                           @"jsonrpc":@"2.0"};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];
...
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

You don't have to escape the `"` (like `\"`), if there are conditions on your parameters, let's say `if(someReason){doNotPutmethodKeyInJSON}`, with a `NSMutableDictionary`, it's easier, and also easier to read (especially your new string with all the `\"` makes it harder to read where could be an issue)
Also, in case of an invalid JSON, you can read the `error`.

I don't know where you put that code, but if it's main thread, that would block the UI, so avoid `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, prefer async calls (with the help of `NSURLSession`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I didn't really understand what you mean with the NSURL session

Comment: It's a class that handle web calls, asynchronously. There are tutorial about it, doc, etc.